# Need to pass address instead of latlong - Google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps v3, Currently it is working fine, if i pass the latitude and longitude in 'position'.  But, I need to pass address instead of latitude and longitude.

```
var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(dat_values[i].lat, dat_values[i].lng);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: ll,
                icon: myImage,
                shadow: myShadow,
             });
```

Kindly anyone suggest.

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

**Here's another similar approach:**

```
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=573/1,+Jangli+Maharaj+Road,+Deccan+Gymkhana,+Pune,+Maharashtra,+India&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

From:
http://amiworks.co.in/talk/how-to-get-latitudelongitude-from-an-address-or-geocoding-using-php/

Answer (score 1):

You've have to use the [Geocoder service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding) to convert the address into a LatLng.

Comment: thanks for your reply duncan, yes, its working. but, it will take little bit time when we need to fetch more markers. Is there any other efficient inbuilt methods in V3 to pass address directly.

Comment: Not to my knowledge; could you prefetch the latlng values for your addresses?

Comment: Yes, `$output_loc=@explode(',',file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q='.$address.'&output=csv&sensor=false'));`